# Laravel image intervention on localhost not working

Tags: image, laravel, intervention

I tried to use this code

```
$image = new ImageManager();
$image = $image->make($path);
```

and namespace is `use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;`

and I get this error 
`localhost is currently unable to handle this request.`

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify which version of intervention you are using.
Still check your namespace it needs Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider.